# fast iteration over two numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying two implement the following problem in python

I have two 1D numpy arrays containing indices in the range from 0 to gridsize-1 (call them i1,i2).
I also have a 1D numpy array with data (call it d).
All three Arrays have the same length.

The arrays with the indices can contain a specific index pair (call it s1,s2)
multiple times.

I now want two map the data array to a 2D Array (call it arr) in order to plot it.
For those index pairs that appear multiple times I want to take the average of the data entries corresponding to these indices.

I tried the following code (without the averaging)

```
d #data array
i1 #first 1D numpy index array
i2 #second 1D numpy index array
gridsize = 1000
arr = np.zeros(gridsize**2)
for i in range(d.size):
    arr[ i1[i], i2[i] ] = d[i]
```

The code is working so far but very slow (about 2s for the size of the arrays which is not acceptable)
Any recommendation to speed it up?
I suggest the problem lies in the the accessing of the individual elements in the arrays. Is there may be a built in numpy function to do that?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Please redefine the variables properly in your code. There is no `d` in your code so what is `d.size` supposed to mean? You wrote the code is working so far. Then plz post the minimal working code. Your indexing inside the for loop is wrong too

Comment: I edited the code. This is the minimal working example if the arrays d, i1, i2 are defined. I thought that this kind of indexing [a,b] is faster than using [a][b] indexing for extracting a single element

Comment: I mean to say post the minimal complete **working** code which takes **2s**. The edited code is no good. `d`, `i1`, `i2` all are undefined. Moreover, `arr` is an array of shape `(1000000,)`. Inside the `for` loop you will get `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume a few things that aren't entirely clear in your question.

- `arr` is 2 dimensional with shape: `(gridsize, gridsize)`
- `i1` `i2` and `d` are all 1 dimensional and the same length

Given these conditions you can fairly straightforwardly use numpy's [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to directly slice `arr` using `i1` and `i2` and assign `d` to the slice:

```
d #data array
i1 #first 1D numpy index array
i2 #second 1D numpy index array
gridsize = 1000
arr = np.zeros((gridsize,gridsize))
arr[i1,i2] = d
```

Comment: @Bazingaa that is why the assumption was defined that `d` is 1 dimensional

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Answering such questions where you/we have to do homework is really annoying

Comment: I will admit finding the right google keywords to come across "numpy integer array indexing" might be a bit difficult if you aren't already a numpy ninja.

Comment: Just Googling the error message is sufficient most of the times.